# Why doesnt this copy class, copy the inner folders

Tags: java, file, recursion

I made a copy class, that takes source and destination folders plus an array of file names. So this class search through the source folder and if it meets a file with the same name as an array element, then it copies that file in the same folder structure and the source one.
Here is the class:

```
public class Copy {
    File src, dest; 
    ArrayList array;

    public Copy(File source, File destination ,ArrayList array) throws IOException{
        this.src = source;
        this.dest = destination;
        this.array = array;

        if(source.isDirectory()){

            //list all the directory contents
            String files[] = source.list();
            for (String element : files){ //Serch in all the files and if it match with a selected format, copies it directory
                if(array.contains(element)){
                    destination.mkdir();
                }
            };

            for (String file : files) {
            //construct the src and dest file structure
            File srcFile = new File(source, file);
            File destFile = new File(destination, file);
            //recursive copy

                new Copy(source,destination, array);
            }
        }
        else{
            //dest.mkdir();
            if(array.contains(source.getName())){
                //if file, then copy it
                //Use bytes stream to support all file types

                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination); 

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int length;
                //copy the file content in bytes 
                while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                in.close();
                out.close();
                System.out.println("File copied from " + source + " to " + destination);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this class is that it only copies files if they are located in first or second inner folders.
For example it can successfully copy a structure like this:

```
- Main Folder
    -Inner Folder1
      -File.pdf
    -Inner Folder2
```

But it cannot copy a structure like this:

```
- Main Folder
    -Inner Folder1
        -Inner Inner Folder1
            -File.pdf
    -Inner Folder2
```

So if the file is located in more than one inner folder, it gives error which is:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Pointing to this line: `new CopyFiles(src,dest, array);

Any idea to solve it?

Comment: Try moving your logic outside of the constructor.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch do you mean converting it to a method and not a class?

Comment: I mean recursively creating object instances just makes work for the garbage collector and it makes debugging more difficult; in your case, a static method (or two) would seem to make more sense (at least to me).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're passing the wrong values to your recursive constructor call.  Try using the temporary variables you created, so that the call becomes `new Copy(srcFile, destFile, Arrays.asList(files));` and also replacing your usages of `ArrayList` with `List`.

EDIT:

There's also an issue with the for loop you have which is trying to make the wrong destination directory.  Remove that loop all together, and add the make directory logic into the following loop.  Once all these changes are made, the if portion of your code should look something like this:

```
//list all the directory contents
String files[] = source.list();
for (String file : files) {
    //construct the src and dest file structure
    File srcFile = new File(source, file);
    File destFile = new File(destination, file);
    //make new directory if needed
    if (srcFile.isDirectory()) {
        destFile.mkdir();
    }
    //recursive copy
    new Copy(srcFile, destFile, Arrays.asList(files));
}
```

This worked for me with your sample directory structure, but the initial destination had to exist.  I tested with the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add("Inner Folder1");
new Copy(new File("C:\\Main Folder"), new File("C:\\New Folder"), array);
```

It should be noted that there are already built in ways to do this in Java.  Unless you're doing this as an exercise, you might want to look at the [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) class in the Java API.

Comment: Same result. Thanks for the post tho.

Comment: Hmmm,, good idea, but the constructor only accepts ArrayLists but files is an array. In that case, how can I change `String files[] = src.list();` to an array list

Comment: @Dan I updated yet again.  My mistake on that one, I should have more carefully looked at the types :)

Comment: Well, honestly replacing arraylist with array can make the problem more complicated. I would look for a way to convert the `files[] array` into an arraylist.

Comment: @Dan `ArrayList` extends `List`, so any code that calls this constructor can still call this constructor, and pass an `ArrayList` without any changes.  The [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method also does the conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks, I made the changes, it complies, but first it copies one not chosen file from the root folder. and then bring up the same error: `he system cannot find the path specified`

Comment: @Dan Hopefully the last edit I need to make ;) I finally tested the code myself (like I should have done from the beginning) and it looked like there was an issue with the loop that was calling `destination.mkdir();`

Comment: Thanks for your post. Well it almost does the job, but with a problem. which is it copies all the files, so basically it doesn't care about what array has. In initial round array has some element that meant to me copied, but in each round `Arrays.asList(files)`, copy the files contents to the array so the initial element get removed. and as all files are in the array so it copies everything. I replaced `Arrays.asList(files)` with `array` and it did the job but it also made a copy of all the folders. just blank folders. So Im stuck in that point. An if statement must do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to use Stings:

```
public Copy(String source, String destination ,ArrayList array) throws IOException{
    this.src = new File(source);
    this.dest = new File(destination);
```

And in the loop you going through each file but you use same source and destination

```
       for (String file : files) {
        //construct the src and dest file structure
        File srcFile = new File(source, file);
        File destFile = new File(destination, file);
            new Copy(source,destination, array);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, changing File to scring would bring up more errors since src and dest will be string and methods such as `src.isDirectory()` would not work on them. If I understood your answer correctly.

Comment: this.src = new File(source); would still keep src.isDirectory() working. But the conversion to string would probably require more changes than I wrote in the snippet. It's just preference. Your problem will probably be inside the loop where the same source and destination is send all the time.

Comment: maybe add more System.out.println(); to have more verbose info what is happening in the loop plus add one in place just before the error line so you will see what is happening before the crash. Some objects have nice toString() methods so you can have human readable info from them.

Comment: Your issue could be your filter condition when in subfolder there is no file it will not create directory regardless if there are any matching files in the subfolder